# need help for Odata query to get 'Configuration' value (3) for 'AppParamConfigs's "Name":"XYZ",

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

with below Odata query

`https://localhost:8080/odata/AppParams(1F2EE62A-8273-E811-81C6-185E0F9B6D7D)?$expand=AppParamConfigs`

I'm getting all the `AppParamConfigs` like below,

```js
{
  "@odata.context":"https://localhost:8080/odata/$metadata#AppParams/$entity","Id":"1f2ee62a-8273-e811-81c6-185e0f9b6d7d","Name":"A","AppParamConfigs":[
    {
      "Id":"722fe62a-8273-e811-81c6-185e0f9b6d7d","Name":"ABC","Configuration":"2"
    },{
      "Id":"732fe62a-8273-e811-81c6-185e0f9b6d7d","Name":"XYZ","Configuration":"3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to get the `Configuration` value (3) for `"Name":"XYZ"` ?

I tried below, but not working

```
https://localhost:8080/odata/AppParams(1F2EE62A-8273-E811-81C6-185E0F9B6D7D)?$expand=AppParamConfigs($select=Name%20eq%20XYZ)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
https://localhost:8080/odata/AppParams(1F2EE62A-8273-E811-81C6-185E0F9B6D7D)?$expand=AppParamConfigs&$filter=Name eq 'XYZ'&$select=Configuration
```

You have to filter first then select.